# Is a C or C++ program that runs without a main() against standards?

Tags: c++, c

I am involved in a discussion with a colleague of mine who says it is possible to "run a program" in C and C++ without main and that too in a hosted environment. I said that's completely incorrect as per the Standards. He then asked me to see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest) link which mentions

> In several years, an entry was submitted that was so patently absurd that it required a new definition of some of the rules for the next year. This is regarded as a high honor. An example is the world's shortest self-reproducing program. The entry was a program zero bytes in length that if run printed zero bytes to the screen (simply an empty file).

I argued that the solution would not be correct as per C and C++ Standards. What do you guys think about this?

Also check out [this](http://www.ioccc.org/1994/smr.hint) link.

Answer (score 11):

Supposedly there have been some compilers that accepted a program without `main()` and supplied their own no-op fallback `main()` from a library. However, such programs are not conforming.

The incidence you're referring to was the `smr` entry of the 1994 IOCCC. However, as published by the contest, it didn't use a C compiler at all! The `Makefile` stanza for it contained:

```
smr: smr.c
    @${RM} -rf smr
    ${CP} smr.c smr
    ${CHMOD} +x smr
```

So it didn't compile it, merely copied the empty `.c` into an empty shell script.

The reason why this was not discarded as completely senseless and off-topic by the judges must have been that the empty file is (at least traditionally) a legal *compilation unit* in C and compiles to an `.o` without problems if you want to -- it just isn't enough to form a complete program.

Comment: At least in C99, a *translation-unit* must contain at least one *external-declaration*, which is either a *function-definition* or a *declaration*.  A *translation-unit* cannot be empty.

Comment: I may be wrong there. I don't have my copy of C90 handy so I can check there whether I just deluded myself.

Comment: I just checked my copy of the C90 standard, and it's the same; a *translation-unit* cannot be empty.  But an empty translation unit is a constraint violation, which requires a warning from a conforming compiler but doesn't forbid it to accept it.

Comment: Such programs could very well be conforming, according to the absurdly loose definition given by the Standard itself.  C99 section 4 paragraph 7: "A _conforming program_ is one that is acceptable to a conforming implementation."  It doesn't say what "acceptable" means; it probably just means that it doesn't reject it (it might accept it with warnings).

Answer (score 8):

`main` is certainly the standard entry point for C programs, but it's possible for non-standard C programs to start somewhere else, for instance Windows GUI apps tend to start at `WinMain` instead, or the linker has an `/ENTRY` directive so you can completely bypass the CRT and start your application with a custom function.

Comment: As I see it, the question is entirely about standards and so only the first clause of your sentence is really directly relevant.

Answer (score 4):

If a program in a hosted environment doesn't have a main then it's not C or C++, as per the standards.

Comment: Not true. The main() is just a convenient default, a default that can be changed (typically through linker options).

Comment: @branko we are talking about the C and C++ languages which are defined by standards

Comment: Formally, for hosted application, but the problem is most Windows GUI programs then fall into that category of "not C or C++". So it would be very impractical terminology to adopt... It's not a technical problem to have a standard `main` for such programs. But they're mostly developed using Microsoft's tools, which actively discourage using standard `main` (in favor of Microsoft-specific silly alternative).

Comment: @Branko: `main` is the standard entry point (for hosted implementations) simply because [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (pdf) says so; see section 5.1.2.2.1.  An implementation may support other behavior, but any program depending on such behavior is not portable.

Comment: @Branko: a *hosted* C/C++ implementation is required to have the `main` function as the entrypoint (C++03 §3.6.1, C99 §5.2.2.1); on *freestanding* implementations, instead, the startup of the application is implementation-defined.

Comment: @David: I'd give you my upvote if you specified that the `main` requirement is only for *hosted implementations*.

Comment: @matteo right I've done that. It seems that my answer is lighting the touchpaper. I'm within touching distance of another peer pressure badge!

Comment: @David: don't, now your answer is (AFAIK) language-lawyer proof, and my upvote got you to the wonderful rep of 49999!

Comment: @matteo thanks! Rep cap means I must wait until tomorrow for the magic 50k!

Comment: @alf I don't think there's any call for such agressive comments. Please be nice!

Comment: @Alf: - sigh - what comment? the "I'm not entirely sure..." or the "you can think that those..."? I don't think that they were "ad-hominem" attacks (I was taught that in an ad-hominem attack you hit your opponent as a person instead of his ideas - thing that I didn't do), but whatever... Still, I'm with you that the from a certain point downwards it's all off-topic, if you wish we may delete the whole thing (from my link to the blog downwards or from your reply, tell me what you prefer) and forget about this stuff.

Comment: to those who said "C/C++" doesnt need a main to run and compile, write me a program that has NO main and try compile it.

Comment: @Flyphe: There's no problem compiling it; any problems are going to occur when you try to link it.  And even so, an implementation is free to support a different entry point as an extension.